# Creating a Backspace Button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I’m trying to create a button that when pressed will remove the last character entered in a text field called “screen” using jQuery. This is the code I already have created but it does not work. Help would be appreciated :)

```
var currentEntry = $("#screen").text();

$("#back").click(function(){
currentEntry = currentEntry.substring(0, currentEntry.length-1);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use **slice()**, **substr()** or **substring()** method to chop the last character from string.

Try the code below using **substr()** method:

```js
$("#back").click(function() {
  var currentEntry = $("#screen").val();
  $("#screen").val(currentEntry.substr(0, currentEntry.length-1));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="screen" type="text" value="screen">
<button id="back" type="button">Click Me!</button>
```

If you are familiar with **slice()** method, you can use it like this way:

```
 $("#screen").val(currentEntry.slice(0, -1));
```

Comment: only works for the first click of the button, subsequent clicks do not have an effect on the text

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the text in DOM, so use [`text()`](https://api.jquery.com/text/) method with a function which helps to update using returned value.

```
$("#back").click(function(){
    $("#screen").text((i, text) => text.slice(0,-1));
});
```

```js
$("#back").click(function() {
  $("#screen").text((i, text) => text.slice(0, -1));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="screen">jshdjhsdhjshjhdsjdhsjdhsjhjshds</div>

<button id="back">back</button>
```

---

If it's a textarea then you have to use [`val()`](https://api.jquery.com/val/) method in same way to update the value.

```
$("#back").click(function(){
    $("#screen").val((i, text) => text.slice(0,-1));
});
```

```js
$("#back").click(function() {
  $("#screen").val((i, text) => text.slice(0, -1));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="screen">jshdjhsdhjshjhdsjdhsjdhsjhjshds</textarea>

<button id="back">back</button>
```